# Is it possible to $lookup from a dict nested in an array?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Let's say that I have the following document model.

```
{"emb": [{"emb_a": a1, "emb_b": b1}, {"emb_a": a2, "emb_b": b2}]}
```

In this structure a1, b1, a2, b2 all represent different ObjectId's.

The goal is to `aggregate` the result of a query so that all results are loaded into memory.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId
from pprint import pprint


class Config(object):
    DATABASE_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test"
    DATABASE = "test_db"


print(f"Connecting to: [{Config.DATABASE}]...")
client = MongoClient(Config.DATABASE_URI)
db = client[Config.DATABASE]
print(f"Connected: [{Config.DATABASE}]...")


a1 = db.a.insert({"a": 1})
a2 = db.a.insert({"a": 2})

b1 = db.b.insert({"b": 1})
b2 = db.b.insert({"b": 2})


def generate_doc():
    return {"emb": [{"emb_a": a1, "emb_b": b1}, {"emb_a": a2, "emb_b": b2}]}


# INSERT A BUNCH OF DOCUMENTS
db.test_collection.insert_many([generate_doc() for i in range(0, 5)])

# AGGREGATION PIPELINE
pprint(
    list(
        db.test_collection.aggregate(
            [
                {
                    "$lookup": {
                        "from": "a",
                        "localField": "emb.emb_a",
                        "foreignField": "_id",
                        "as": "emb.emb_a",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$lookup": {
                        "from": "b",
                        "localField": "emb.emb_b",
                        "foreignField": "_id",
                        "as": "emb.emb_b",
                    }
                },
            ]
        )
    )
)


client.drop_database(Config.DATABASE)
```

Below is what the result of that script is...

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5cd0af6deb62e064cd99bae4'),
  'emb': {'emb_a': [{'_id': ObjectId('5cd0af6deb62e064cd99badc'), 'a': 1},
                    {'_id': ObjectId('5cd0af6deb62e064cd99badd'), 'a': 2}],
          'emb_b': []}}
```

But what I would like to get back is...

```
{
    "emb": [
        {"emb_a": {'_id': ObjectId('5cd0af6deb62e064cd99badc'), 'a': 1}, "emb_b": {'_id': ObjectId('5cd0af6deb62e064cd99badd'), 'b': 1}},
        {"emb_a": {'_id': ObjectId('5cd0af6deb62e064cd99bade'), 'a': 2}, "emb_b": {'_id': ObjectId('5cd0af6deb62e064cd99badf'), 'b': 2}}
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You query is not working because you are overwriting `emb` property with the `as` clause. Try with this one:

```
db.test_collection.aggregate(
[
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "a",
            "localField": "emb.emb_a",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "emb_a",
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "b",
            "localField": "emb.emb_b",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "emb_b",
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            '_id': 0,
            'emb': 0
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                'emb': {
                    'emb_a': '$emb_a',
                    'emb_b': '$emb_b'
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Here instead you keep both `emb` and nested documents `emb_a` and `emb_b`. In the third pipeline stage I remove `emb` (with the projection) because I do not need it anymore for lookup and in the end I rebuild it using the previously computed `emb_a` and `emb_b`.